# ADO.NET Entity Model - Dynamically assigning TableAttribute

Tags: c#, attributes, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a need for a project to allow the user to setup database info and table names in the config file. I want to use ADO.NET Entity Model to use the LINQ and just stay away from SQL the most I can to make it easier on myself. Is there a way to dynamically assign what table a Class needs to access for the modal?

For example:
This is what it looks like normally

```
    [Table("database.table")]
    public partial class table
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(TypeName = "usmallint")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to dynamically set the TableAttribute so the model knows what table to access for the class.

```
    [Table(Config.DBName + Config.tableName)]
    public partial class table
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(TypeName = "usmallint")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help or letting me know that it is not possible would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want this?  Attribute params have to be compile-time constants, so not really.  Why not have a class named `Orders` for things in the `Orders` table and a class named `LineItems` for the `LineItems` table?  if you're trying to avoid the magic strings you can use `nameof(ClassName)` to always name the table after the name of the class...

Comment: @GPW the reason is that it is a plugin for an application and it can possibly have multiple instances running in the same database. So if I have the same two tables with the same name for multiple instances, it runs into an issue. However, I guess one way around this I could have a master table for multiple instances and just put another column tieing it into the process that it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but I *think* you can do this via implementing custom *conventions* - if you're using EF6 at least.

First, you need to create a custom Convention:

```
public class CustomTableNameConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EntitySet>
{
    private readonly string _tablePrefix;

    public CustomTableNameConvention(string tablePrefix)
    {
        _tablePrefix = tablePrefix;
    }

    public void Apply(EntitySet item, DbModel model)
    {
        //change table name.
        item.Table = $"{_tablePrefix}" + item.Table;
    }
}
```

Next, you need to add this convention in the `OnModelCreating` method of your Context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionstring)
    {
    } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //get the dynamic table prefix...
        var myAppPrefix = "user1";
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CustomTableNameConvention(myAppPrefix));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<SomeModel> { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

... Then, whenever the model *in this application instance* starts up, it should run through the above when deciding what the table name(s) should be.
Just replace the `myAppPrefix = ...` code with a call to an appropriate service to get the prefix for this instance.

the obvious caveat with this is that you cannot use a value for the prefix which is returned from the database (at least, not via this Context), as the Context isn't yet initialised.. so you'd have to either store it in settings or pass it in some other way.

Hope this helps.